# Lambda Invocation error with callback called: metrics show no errors

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a Lambda function in AWS that export logs from Cloudfront to Elasticsearch.

From the AWS console, I still have a warining in front of `Invocation error`, though the metrics show there is none for more than 24hours.

[image]

[image]

A typical workflow of logs looks like

```
START RequestId: 302f0b95-7856-11e8-9486-55b3f10e7d4e Version: $LATEST
Request complete
END RequestId: 302f0b95-7856-11e8-9486-55b3f10e7d4e
REPORT RequestId: 302f0b95-7856-11e8-9486-55b3f10e7d4e Duration: 794.93 ms Billed Duration: 800 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 52 MB
```

There is no error in the logs, and the only thing I guess could trigger this invocation error is that sometimes two request starts at the same time

```
09:01:47
START RequestId: 63cd00e1-7856-11e8-8f96-1f900def8e65 Version: $LATEST 
09:01:47
START RequestId: 63e1e7f3-7856-11e8-97e6-3792244f6ab0 Version: $LATEST
```

Except from this, I don't understand where this error comes from. 
Do I miss something? Or do I have to wait more than 24hours before the satus change? May be there is a way to pinpoint the error with AWS console/API that I did not find about?

Would be happy to hear what you think about this.

Edit: In case you'd like to take a look at the code itself.

```
var aws  = require('aws-sdk');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var async = require('async');
const CloudFrontParser = require('cloudfront-log-parser');

var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

var s3 = new aws.S3();

var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: process.env.ES_HOST,
  log: 'trace',
  keepAlive: false
});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    var srcKey = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

    async.waterfall([
        function fetchLogFromS3(next){
            console.log('Fetching compressed log from S3...');
            s3.getObject({
               Bucket: srcBucket,
               Key: srcKey
            },
            next);
        },
        function uncompressLog(response, next){
            console.log("Uncompressing log...");
            zlib.gunzip(response.Body, next);
        },
        function publishNotifications(jsonBuffer, next) {
            console.log('Filtering log...');
            var json = jsonBuffer.toString();

            var records;
            CloudFrontParser.parse(json, { format: 'web' }, function (err, accesses) {
              if(err){
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                records = accesses;
              }
            });

            var bulk = [];
            records.forEach(function(record) {
              bulk.push({"index": {}})
              bulk.push(record);
            });

            client.bulk({
              index: process.env.ES_INDEXPREFIX,
              type: 'log',
              body: bulk
            }, function(err, resp, status) {
              if(err) {
                console.log('Error: ', err);
              }
              console.log(resp);
              next(); 
            });

            console.log('CloudFront parsed:', records);

        }
    ], function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Failed to send data: ', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Successfully send data.');
        }
        callback(null, 'success');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly return information back to the caller.
Here's the related documentation:

> The Node.js runtimes v6.10 and v8.10 support the optional callback
> parameter. You can use it to explicitly return information back to the
> caller. The general syntax is:
>
> callback(Error error, Object result); Where:
>
> error – is an optional parameter that you can use to provide results
> of the failed Lambda function execution. When a Lambda function
> succeeds, you can pass null as the first parameter.
>
> result – is an optional parameter that you can use to provide the
> result of a successful function execution. The result provided must be
> JSON.stringify compatible. If an error is provided, this parameter is
> ignored.
>
> If you don't use callback in your code, AWS Lambda will call it
> implicitly and the return value is null.
>
> When the callback is called (explicitly or implicitly), AWS Lambda
> continues the Lambda function invocation until the event loop is
> empty.

**The following are example callbacks:**

```
    callback();     // Indicates success but no information returned to the caller. 
    callback(null); // Indicates success but no informatio returned to the caller. 
    callback(null, "success");  // Indicates success with information returned to the caller. 
    callback(error); //  Indicates error with error information returned to the caller
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

Comment: Thanks! I've just changed `callback(null, 'Done');` to `callback(null, 'success');` But still have the same error. Should I wait long?

Comment: And, by the way, I believe calling `callback(null, 'Done');` should be enough, shouldn't it?

Comment: If you want to see the invocation error you should go with this callback(error)

Comment: The general syntax is: callback(Error error, Object result);

Comment: During the callback of `async`, I call `console.log('Successfully send data.');` in the case of no error. I can see this in the logs, meaning no error has been found, hence no error object has been created. So `callback(err);` is  called with `err` being `null`, meaning `success`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes,Another thing is the error did not happen in the last 24 hours (the count is 0), according the print screen. So you need to change the interval to last week and find out when did this error occurred. Once you have this investigate the lambda logs again.

Comment: The error did not appear the last 24+ hours because I corrected an issue with my code. Since corrected, the count stays to zero.

Comment: I guess  I can't help, because I don't understand how you fixed the error if it was not in the logs, and on top of this according the documentation you shouldn't be getting any invocation errors because you always return 'success' in onError.

Comment: The error was really trivial (almost as trivial as a typo). I don't understand either my issue, all the logs are indeed sent and present in ES, and there is no error shown in the metrics. 
But thanks for your help, really appreciate :)